# What do I need to transfer video from a camcorder to my (linux) PC?

Tags: memory-card, camcorder

I plan on purchasing this, [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0032UWTQI/ref=olp_product_details?ie=UTF8&me=&seller=](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0032UWTQI)

Along with this memory card: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B002GEQDK4/ref=oss_product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002GEQDK4)

It seems the camcorder comes with a USB cable. Would I use that separately in addition to the memory card or how would it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when you plug in a camcorder to the computer with a memory card in it, it should show up as an MTP device with video files in it.

Comment: Ah, so the USB that comes with it is the only thing I need then?

Comment: Always good to have a backup plan, but yupsolutely.

Comment: @mederomuraliev or just make sure the camera is completely powered down, then move the memory card to a memory card reader connected to your computer, and use it as a regular storage device. Most laptops come with readers built-in.